# How do I install the Resharper Command Line Tools?

Tags: command-line, resharper

I have downloaded the Resharper Command Line Tool (Inspect Code), and I have saved the set up. But I do not find any installation file in the folder.

How do I install it in my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I downloaded the [Resharper Command Line Tools](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+ReSharper+Command+Line+Tools) (from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html)), it was just a zip file with the executables inside of it.  So unzip it to a folder, and just run `inspectcode.exe`.

**Edit:** I just downloaded it again and it's still a zip file; there is no installer.

Comment: But how do we specify the solution path or the project file. It says no solution file. how do we specify it?

Comment: Pass it as an argument (without a switch); it'll be something like `inspectCode.exe C:\path\to\your.sln`.  Review the usage and possible switches of inspectCode.exe by executing `inspectCode.exe /h`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Also can you let me know what is the default path the output xml will be stored? I could not find in the solution path or anywhere.

Comment: Looks like it won't write results unless you pass /o.